# How to find total variation of a signed measure??

Tags: measure-theory, total-variation, signed-measures

Let $(X,F,\nu)$ be a signed measure on the sigma algebra F.
now by Jordan-Hahn decomposition theorem $\nu = \nu_1 - \nu_2$, where $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are positive and mutually singular, and such measures are unique.

now to prove

$$\sup_{\text{finite partitions $E_k$ of $X$}} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} | \nu(E_k) | = \nu_1 + \nu_2$$

I am stuck to show this plz help me..

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the supremum over finite partitions not suffice in defining total variation of complex measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359464/why-does-the-supremum-over-finite-partitions-not-suffice-in-defining-total-varia)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor no this is actually not my question

Comment: The title looks different, but the answer to the linked question works for your question too

Comment: @HallaSurvivor ho this ans help to solve the one sided inequality..

Answer (score 0):

Let $|\nu| = \nu_1 + \nu_2$. By the triangle inequality, for any $E \subset X$, $|\nu(E)| \leq |\nu|(E)$. For any finite partition $E_1, \dots, E_n$ of $X$,
$$\sum_{k}|\nu(E_k)| \leq \sum_{k}|\nu|(E_k) = |\nu|(X).$$
This shows that the sup is $\leq |\nu|(X)$. To get the other inequality, let $E_1, E_2$ be a Hahn decomposition for $X$.

Comment: I really did not get aftethe last lie by "Hahn decomposition" ..Since i tried it for yesterday , several times i tried to use the fact they are singular which yu are talking named "Hahn decomposition",but really i am failed to use this fact  in the exact place wwhere it is needed.That's why i am stuck..Can you plz help me out by giving some more hints plz ,i am really stuck on it since yesterday.

Comment: @VishnudasaSrinivasan $\nu(E_1) = \nu_1(X)$ and $\nu(E_2) = -\nu_2(X)$

Comment: it was helpful i finally did it thanks.. particularly this lie underlying the language of singularity i did not look so closely that's why i ws stuck to use singularity..