# Strict linear independence of probability measures

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, information-geometry

Let $X$ be a measurable space and $P_1, \dotsc, P_K$ be probability measures on it. If $\mu$ is a reference $\sigma$-finite measure with respect to which all $P_k$ are absolutely continuous, [this machine learning paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/219e052492f4008818b8adb6366c7ed6-Paper.pdf) defines *strict linear independence* by the property that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb R^K\setminus \{0\}$ it holds that
$$
\int\left| \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k \frac{\mathrm dP_k}{\mathrm d\mu} \right| \mathrm{d}\mu \neq 0,
$$
which can be rewritten as $\left|\sum_k\lambda_k P_k\right|(X) \neq 0$ using [standard rules of Radon-Nikodym differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties).

Writing $Q = \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k P_k$ and using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4849531/551592), this should be equivalent to the following:

> Distributions $P_1, \dotsc, P_K$ are strictly linearly independent iff for each $\lambda\neq 0$ there exists a measurable set $A$ such that $\lambda_1 P_1(A) + \cdots + \lambda_K P_K(A) \neq 0.$

This looks like a pretty general definition and I'm sure it must have been defined and investigated by measure theorists or information geometers. At the same time, I can't find any reference on this topic. I wonder if you could recommend books or academic publications investigating this definition and its implications.